# Difference between ISTQB Advanced Test Analyst certification vs ISTQB Test automation engineer certification?

Tags: learning, istqb, certification

What's the difference between `ISTQB Advanced Test Analyst certification` vs `ISTQB Test automation engineer certification`?

How can a manual tester with no automation testing project experience prepare for these exams?

Which one should prepare first?

Comment: if you have no experience with automated testing, then I am wondering why you would want to get certification for automated testing? what value do you expect from it?

Answer (score 2):

The different syllabus sections relevant for each level can be found here:

- https://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root/advanced-level/advanced-level-technical-test-analyst.html
- https://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root/advanced-level/advanced-level-test-analyst.html

For ISTQB, it helps to have hands-on experience beforehand, but you should manage by studying the course and taking a training.

Answer (score 1):

For taking up the ISTQB Advanced Level Certification, you must hold ISTQB Foundation Level Certification. Refer the [official ISTQB site](https://www.istqb.org/about-as/istqb-levels-and-modules.html) to know more about the certification levels

1. Know the latest [syllabus](https://www.istqb.org/downloads/syllabi/foundation-level-syllabus.html) and understand the structure of the exam
2. Self-study is the best option

Answer (score 1):

My answer to Q1:

I attempted both the certifications in which failed in ATT and passed in TAE hence I am more relevant in answering here.
ATT: It was the exam I chose to take when I was 4+ years experienced and failed with 47% due to following reasons:

1. Complex combinations of questions
2. Not even relevant to Testing
   Projects

But I attempted TAE certification after having 12 years of experience and cleared the exam. I liked the certification on TAE for following reasons:

1. There is no code involved in this certification but a lot of practice examples related to projects are being discussed
2. I managed to map the exam questions direct to my automation testing experiences.

Some useful resources on both these certifications:

- [ATT](https://certificate.isqi.org/istqb-agile-technical-tester-sample-exam-answers)
- [TAE](https://cheatography.com/narayanan-palani/cheat-sheets/istqb-test-automation-engineering/)

My Answer to Q2:

I had 4+ years automation experience hence the TAE certification has been more relevant. But I don't recommend it if you are not having any project experience. The purpose of TAE is to serve clarifications or following best practices in test automation project; Without project experience, it will not be useful. That is my honest answer (not opinion)

Sharing one of my friend's post related to it:

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/activity-6698379357737562112-A0FF

But ATT is more suitable for manual testing experience and relevant to formula such as Boundary Value Analysis, Equivalence Partitioning, Static Testing, Dynamic Testing, White Box Testing etc.